# free code camp "MongoDB and Mongoose - Create and Save a Record of a Model

Tags: mongodb, mongoose-schema

I wrote this code, but free code camp get me a message "Creating and saving a db item should succeed (Test timed out)".
there is my code

```
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);

var createAndSavePerson = function(done) {
  var person = new Person({name: "John Doe", age: 87, favoriteFoods: ["something", "something"]});

  person.save(function(err, data) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    done(null, data)
  });
};
```

what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

In general, this would be the process:

---

Create the schema and the model

```
const personSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number,
    favoriteFoods: Array
})

const Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema)
```

---

Save a new person based on the model

```
var createAndSavePerson = function() {
  var person = new Person({name: "John Doe", age: 87, favoriteFoods: ["something", "something"]});

  person.save(function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
     console.log(err)
    }
    console.log(data)
  });
};
```

For the purposes of the freeCodeCamp you could just try `person.save()` instead of the entire function for it.

Answer (score 0):

I have been learning from freecodecamp recently, and was stuck with the same error on the problem -  "Creating and saving a db item should succeed (Test timed out)".
The solution to the problem is tough to figure out, because actually there is nothing wrong with the code in .js file where you are creating and saving the instance of your person object a.k.a document.

The problem lies in having access rights for ip address for mongoDB.

**Allow access from all IP addresses**

- On the left side of the screen, click on Network Access.
- Click the green Add IP Address button.
- In the modal, click the ALLOW ACCESS FROM ANYWHERE button. You should
  see 0.0.0.0/0 in the Access List Entry entry field.
- Click the green Confirm button.[image]